# Sending addr messages to nodes

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, bitcoin-cli, p2p

I came across [this resource](https://ultraconfig.com.au/blog/introduction-to-the-bitcoin-network-protocol-using-python-and-tcp-sockets/) that can be potentially used to send messages to nodes.

How would I go about sending addr messages to nodes?
Is there a built in utility that I could use(bitcoin-cli) or do I have to resort writing a script?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If you run a full node (e.g. Bitcoin Core) you will send addr messages to nodes by default and help them find other peers (part of the P2P protocol). What exactly do you want to do beyond this? You want to send them specific addr messages at the time of your choosing or you want to experiment with your own script?

Comment: I am trying to experiment with my own script to actually see how the buckets are populated with and without the use of an asmap.

Comment: Ah ok, cool. Afaik there isn't any built in utility. You'll have to write a script to send additional addr messages that Core wouldn't send.

Comment: @VinayShetty This could be helpful: https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/blob/master/examples/send-addrs-msg.py. I tried using it and see an addr message in wireshark although script looks outdated.